# Reinitialize a changed DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-events

A page has several sections dynamically loaded via ajax. The content of each section has many elements and more script and css and is unknown before the initial page load. I've used MutationObserver and jQuery .on() in previous but simpler cases with known content to be loaded but even if the content is known in advance in this case, it would be too cumbersome to try to attach an event handler to each element and run the related script that sets up the page or section. I haven't been able to get replaceWith clone (see example) to work as I had hoped. I'm not concerned about efficiency for the client, only the server, which is why the content is broken up on the page until explicitly requested. How can the DOM be reinitialized to account for the new content?

Pseudo code:

```
<a href='javascript:load_1();'>Search for cars</a>
<div id='section1'></div>
<a href='javascript:load_2();'>Talk about dogs</a>
<div id='section2'></div>
<a href='javascript:load_3();'>View schedule</a>
<div id='section3'></div>
```

Example to load section2:

```
var loaded_2 = false;
function load_2(){ 
    if(!loaded_2){
    loaded_2 = true; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/talkAboutDogs",
        success: function(data){
        if(data.message && data.message !== "")
        {
            section2.innerHTML=data.message; //This works: section2 gets loaded with message content
            //This suggestion found elsewhere is ineffective:
            //var docClone = $("#document").clone(true);
            //$("#document").replaceWith(docClone.clone(true)); //self-surgery during code execution?
            //What to do?
        }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if(XMLHttpRequest.responseText !== "")
        {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
        }
    });
    }
    return;
};
```

Comment: small note: don't put JS in your HTM like you're showing in your pseudocode. HTML4.01 and its legacy practices died well over a decade ago =) Put your JS in your JS file, and if you need click handling, do that there (either in plain JS using `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener`, or using jQuery since you're doing that already, using `$(...).on(...)`)

Comment: It is unclear what `$("#document")` is... But as-is, your code is saying `$(element).replaceWith(a_copy_of_self)`... And it also is unclear why attempting to to this.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The JS is created dynamically as well and is used extensively throughout the framework in use. It is generally appended to the end of the content.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The replaceWith document clone method to trigger initialization has been suggested several times elsewhere for essentially the same problem but I haven't found anecdotal evidence that it works.

Comment: Well... It depends on *when* you clone the original element... Actually, you clone it after the `section2` modification. So if `section2` is a child of `#document`, the new changes are in the cloned element.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The clone and replaceWith method as written is ineffective. I doubt it's even possible that it could be made to work.

Comment: The `replaceWith()` method wille remove a DOM element and replace it with another. `ReplaceWith(self)` is useless. And it does not trigger any *initialization* whatsoever. In some cases, `replaceWith(self_before_changes)` may be useful... Like to reset a big form having dynamically added fields, for example. -- What you wish to do is unclear.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette replaceWith() apparently will not solve the problem. The suggestion came from another similar question that remained unsolved. The new content needs to be initialized or reinitialize the whole page with the new content even though the previously existing content had been initialized already. New event handlers are needed and initialization such as is typically done after window.onload or $(document).ready(), etc.

Comment: I just don't know what should be *initialised*. If it is about some event handlers, you should be using event delegation. If it is plugin instanciation, it will be different based on the specific plugin.